# What did John Nash publish post-illness?

Tags: math-history, mathematicians

I've searched for this from time to time and never been able to find a single research paper he published since 1960.  Every account of his later work seems to finesse this.  The [Abel prize](http://www.abelprize.no/nyheter/vis.html?tid=63693) page for example has no links or citations to his work.  Has he in fact published significantly post-illness?